# CSS sprites not displaying their image

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

OK so I have been having issues getting sprites to work on my website, so I decided to rewrite the w3 sprite tutorial from scratch to see what I was doing wrong. Here is the code I wrote:

test.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <img src="img_navsprites.gif" alt="">
  <img src="img_trans.gif" alt="" id="home"><br><br>
  <img src="img_trans.gif" alt="" id="next">
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```css
#home{
  width:46px;
  height:44px;
  background: url(img_navsprites.gif) 0 0;
}
#next{
  width:43px;
  height:44px;
  background: url(img_navsprites.gif) -91px 0;
}
```

When I open this in Chrome the first image shows up but not the separate images. I have no idea what I have done wrong, by every account this code should work.

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Comment: How does the `img_navsprites` looks?

Comment: @Rotan075 you can see the image here [W3](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp)

Comment: @jgonzales394 Are you sure that this is all your CSS within your website? It should work!

Comment: It is, what I did was go offline with the code and test it locally on my computer.

Comment: Do you have a copy of the gif files in your local directory?

Comment: If you would like to see code live [click here](http://reapersoftwares.com/test/test.html)

Comment: It works. You give background-image to the img element which doesn't have src so you see the crashed image.

Comment: W3 usually refers to the W3C, the organisation that manages a lot of the specifications for web standards. Don't confuse them with W3Schools, purveyor of mediocre (formally appallingly bad) tutorials and references.

Comment: @jgonzales394 [Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/vrLxoL4g/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will look closely to example on W3 then you will see that you need "img_trans.gif" to be proper img file as well. It is just one pixel image in their example.
IMG element displays 'alt' attribute, which is empty in your code, when your 'src' is incorrect.

Comment: OK, so I went and changed the '<img>'  tags to '<div>' tags and that did fix issue. Thank you. Now I just need to find out why it will not work on my actual project. *sigh*